# Divide Geo Line in specified interval based on start and end geo-coordinates

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, geometry, gmap.net

I have two geo coordinates (Start and End Points) and I am able to create a line between them. Suppose these two coordinates are at a distance of 30 meters then I need to find every geolocation of points at an interval of 3 meters. So there are 10 such points which are required.

I am able to find the points by some formulas but these points are not in the same direction as the line formed by start and end points.

What I have done so far is below...

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
public class AzimuthCalculator
{
    public const double range = 0.00186411F; // in Miles
    public const double rangeInMeter = 3F;
    public const double factor = 0.003F;
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        double sLatitude = 28.6187763214111F;
        double sLongitude = 77.2093048095703F;

        double eLatitude = 28.6191763153134F;
        double eLongitude = 77.2097146511078F;

        Console.WriteLine($"Start Point : {sLatitude}, {sLongitude}");
        Console.WriteLine($"End Point : {eLatitude},{eLongitude}"); 

        double distance = CalculateDistance(sLatitude, sLongitude, eLatitude, eLongitude);
        Console.WriteLine($"Distance : {distance} miles, {MilesToMeter(distance)} meter, {(distance * 1.60934)} kilometer");
        distance = distance * 1.60934;

        double numberOfIDS = distance/factor;

        double azimuthAngle = DegreeBearing(sLatitude, sLongitude, eLatitude, eLongitude);
        Console.WriteLine($"Azimuth : {azimuthAngle}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IDS : {numberOfIDS}");

        double constantAzimuth = (azimuthAngle/numberOfIDS);

        azimuthAngle = constantAzimuth;
        Console.WriteLine($"Original Azimuth : {azimuthAngle}");

        double[] getAnotherPoint = pointRadialDistance(sLatitude, sLongitude, azimuthAngle, distance);
        Console.WriteLine($"End Point : {getAnotherPoint[0]},{getAnotherPoint[1]}");

        distance = 0.003;   // 3 meter

        getAnotherPoint = pointRadialDistance(sLatitude, sLongitude, azimuthAngle, distance);


        int totalIDS = (Int32)(numberOfIDS);

        for(int i=0;i<totalIDS;i++)
        {
            sLatitude = getAnotherPoint[0];
            sLongitude = getAnotherPoint[1];
            distance = 0.003;
            Console.WriteLine($"new PointLatLng({getAnotherPoint[0]},{getAnotherPoint[1]}),");
            getAnotherPoint = pointRadialDistance(sLatitude, sLongitude, azimuthAngle, distance);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }       

    static double rEarth = 6371.01F; // Earth radius in km
    static double epsilon = 0.000001F;

    public static double[] pointRadialDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double bearing, double distance)
    {
        double rlat1 = ToRad(lat1);
        double rlon1 = ToRad(lon1);
        double rbearing = ToRad(bearing);
        double rdistance = distance / rEarth; // normalize linear distance to radian angle

        double rlat = Math.Asin( Math.Sin(rlat1) * Math.Cos(rdistance) + Math.Cos(rlat1) * Math.Sin(rdistance) * Math.Cos(rbearing));
        double rlon = 0.0F;

        if ( Math.Cos(rlat) == 0 || Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rlat)) < epsilon) // Endpoint a pole
            rlon=rlon1;
        else
            rlon = ((rlon1 - Math.Asin( Math.Sin(rbearing) * Math.Sin(rdistance) / Math.Cos(rlat) ) + Math.PI ) % (2*Math.PI) ) - Math.PI;

        double lat = ToDegrees(rlat);
        double lon = ToDegrees(rlon);

        double[] listNew = new double[2];
        listNew[0] = lat;
        listNew[1] = lon;
        return (listNew);
    }

    public static GeoLocation FindPointAtDistanceFrom(GeoLocation startPoint, double initialBearingRadians, double distanceKilometres)
    {
        const double radiusEarthKilometres = 6371.01;
        var distRatio = distanceKilometres / radiusEarthKilometres;
        var distRatioSine = Math.Sin(distRatio);
        var distRatioCosine = Math.Cos(distRatio);

        var startLatRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Latitude);
        var startLonRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Longitude);

        var startLatCos = Math.Cos(startLatRad);
        var startLatSin = Math.Sin(startLatRad);

        var endLatRads = Math.Asin((startLatSin * distRatioCosine) + (startLatCos * distRatioSine * Math.Cos(initialBearingRadians)));

        var endLonRads = startLonRad
            + Math.Atan2(
                Math.Sin(initialBearingRadians) * distRatioSine * startLatCos,
                distRatioCosine - startLatSin * Math.Sin(endLatRads));

        return new GeoLocation
        {
            Latitude = RadiansToDegrees(endLatRads),
            Longitude = RadiansToDegrees(endLonRads)
        };
    }

    public struct GeoLocation
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }

    public static double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
    {
        const double degToRadFactor = Math.PI / 180;
        return degrees * degToRadFactor;
    }

    public static double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        const double radToDegFactor = 180 / Math.PI;
        return radians * radToDegFactor;
    }

    public static double CalculateDistance(double sLatitude, double sLongitude, double eLatitude, double eLongitude)
    {
        var radiansOverDegrees = (Math.PI / 180.0);

        var sLatitudeRadians = sLatitude * radiansOverDegrees;
        var sLongitudeRadians = sLongitude * radiansOverDegrees;
        var eLatitudeRadians = eLatitude * radiansOverDegrees;
        var eLongitudeRadians = eLongitude * radiansOverDegrees;

        var dLongitude = eLongitudeRadians - sLongitudeRadians;
        var dLatitude = eLatitudeRadians - sLatitudeRadians;

        var result1 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLatitude / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.Cos(sLatitudeRadians) * Math.Cos(eLatitudeRadians) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLongitude / 2.0), 2.0);

        // Using 3956 as the number of miles around the earth
        var result2 = 3956.0 * 2.0 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(result1), Math.Sqrt(1.0 - result1));

        return result2;
    }   

    static double DegreeBearing(double lat1, double lon1,double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        var dLon = ToRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var dPhi = Math.Log(Math.Tan(ToRad(lat2) / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.Tan(ToRad(lat1) / 2 + Math.PI / 4));
        if (Math.Abs(dLon) > Math.PI)
        dLon = dLon > 0 ? - (2 * Math.PI - dLon) : (2 * Math.PI + dLon);
        return ToBearing(Math.Atan2(dLon, dPhi));            
    }

    public static double ToRad(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public static double ToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
    }

    public static double ToBearing(double radians)
    {
        // convert radians to degrees (as bearing: 0...360)
        return (ToDegrees(radians) + 360) % 360;
    }

    public static double MeterToMiles(double meter)
    {
        return (meter / 1609.344);
    }

    public static double MilesToMeter(double miles)
    {
        return (miles * 1609.344);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you calculate wrong bearing from right one here `constantAzimuth = (azimuthAngle/numberOfIDS);` and use it later?

You can calculate intermediate points on the great circle path using approach [described here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)  (essentially it is SLERP - spherical linear interpolation)

```
Formula:    
a = sin((1−f)⋅δ) / sin δ
b = sin(f⋅δ) / sin δ
x = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ cos λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos λ2
y = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ sin λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin λ2
z = a ⋅ sin φ1 + b ⋅ sin φ2
φi = atan2(z, √x² + y²)
λi = atan2(y, x)
where   
    f is fraction along great circle route (f=0 is point 1, f=1 is point 2), 
    δ is the angular distance d/R between the two points.
```

Comment: but when I have not written constantAzimuth = (azimuthAngle/numberOfIDS), still I have the same problem

Comment: So you can calculate `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point` for distances 3,6,9... meters and given `sLatitude/sLongitude` without modification these coordinates (I doubt why you change everything again and again)